# Dynamic content within an attachment

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can we have dynamic content built within an attachment. E.g. i have a disclosure statement that needs to be attached with an email.
This statement however will contain the customers name and address.

Is this possible with Email studio in Marketing cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot (in theory) influence content of attachments in Marketing Cloud, based on subscriber data. You will be using [AttachFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm) function to add a file to an outbound email. You cannot have Marketing Cloud generate a file and attach it. AttachFile function takes, a.o. a URL to the file as an argument. If the source of this file is a system able to adapt the generated content based on specific attributes, you can append them in the URL, as in this example:

```
%%[

var @fileName, @fileAlias, @subscriberKey
set @fileName = Concat("https://example.com/filegenerator/somefile_pdf?uid=",@subscriberKey)
set @fileAlias = "somefile.pdf"

AttachFile("HTTP", @fileName, @fileAlias)

]%%
```

Not knowing more about your specific use case nor systems involved in generating attachments, it is difficult to be more specific.

Be aware that file attachments is an add-on to most SFMC licenses, so please check with your Account Executive before proceeding further with the implementation.

Comment: You have answered what i was after Lukas. Thank you.